# Applying Digital Signatures to documents on a web application

Tags: sdk, signature

I'm developing a web application that deals with sensitive digital documents, and I want to ensure their integrity and authenticity. How can I implement a solution that uses digital signatures to achieve this? Are there any best practices or libraries that I should consider for adding digital signature functionality to my application?

I´ve seen there are many SDKs and solutions not sure if they are all valid or what to look for.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with SIGNply SDK:
[https://gitlab.com/firmar.online/signply-sdk-demo-android][1]

This SDK integrates into your own application and allows you to sign any PDF document with the maximum guarantees of integrity. Signatures verified with Adobe Reader.